# How to redirect to a jsp from a method in java?

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Java Spring MVC website project.
I have a method which checks if user inputs were valid. Something along this line :

```
    public List<Offer> pullOffers(String producer,int minPrice, int maxPrice){
    if (minPrice > maxPrice){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Min price cannot be grater than Max price");
    }
```

Instead of throwing an exception i'd like to redirect user to one of my .jsp files, basically send a GET request for one of them. 
How do i do that within this method ?

Jsp will contain some error info and a redirect to index.jsp button etc.
If more info needed pls tell. Have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

So i found a way to display the jsp i want in much easier way.

```
@ExceptionHandler(IllegalArgumentException.class)
public String handle(Exception ex){
    return "no_offers_found_screen";
}
```

In controller class i made a method with @ExceptionHandler annotation and it sees exception thrown from my service method. 
And from that method, since its within a controller class i can easly redirect user to the page i want.